# where do we define new colType AddIn for pentaho CDE dashboards?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to register a new AddIn for the Table component.

Looking at the source in cdf / cdf-core / cdf / js / addIns / coltypes.js
this seems not very difficult. 
However, where do I define this code? The final step is (taken from the dataBar colType)

```
Dashboards.registerAddIn("Table", "colType", new AddIn(dataBar));
```

can I run this in a javascript resource attached to the Layout section of the dashboard?

I think my question is ver similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869195/where-can-i-create-the-relative-sparkline-addin-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Addins need to be registered only on dashboard render time.